# Azure websites/webapp - Sometimes my site restarts by itself

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been experiencing a problem at the last months.

Sometimes (it usually happens like once a month) my site gets offline. It stays offline for about 30 minutes. Checking Kudu, I've discovered that what happens is that my site is getting restarting (but I didn't ask for any restart). I start believing that it could be a scale problem, but I don't actually have so many simultaneous users (usually something like 50).

Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to upgrading the VM the site is on. It might help to scale to more than one instance. But generally there's not downtime during the relocation of the site if you are using Web Apps, so I'd recommend contacting Azure support about the outage.

Comment: We don't have support subscription :(